# Is there a naming pattern for extensions to standard datatypes in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an extension to Swift String datatype and have added a few properties & functions to it. Currently I am prefixing xt before the property and function names which are my extensions to the standard data types.

I am wondering if there is a naming pattern that other developers use so that my code is consistent is what is established out there.

Here is some sample code:

```
extension String {
  var xtFloatValue: Float {
    return (self as NSString).floatValue
  }

  var xtLength: Int {
    return countElements(self)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any naming pattern to extension methods. I haven't seen extension methods having prefixes either. Why do you want to differentiate between the two anyways?

Comment: I think it serves two purposes - (1) when reading code, it is clear that it is an extension - helps maintainability. (2) protects from clashing with a func/property on a standard type being defined in future.

Comment: There shouldn't be any clashing since the compiler will know at compile time. If a function or property is added to an SDK at a later time then your application will simply not compile.

Comment: That's a good point @bjtitus